# getting context and activity object null in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, android-toast

I am trying to toast a message from separate class which is not an activity. To do so, I know I need context of activity. But I do not know why I am getting null context in that class

here is my class for toasting message

```
public class Notifier {

public Notifier(){

}

public Notifier(Context ctx, MainActivity activity){
Log.d("Constructor call", "dd");
context = ctx;
activity = activity;
}

public void toast(String message){  
messageData = message;
Log.d("Notifier Data", messageData);

while(context == null || activity == null){
    Log.d("Context", "issue");
    try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException exception){
    exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "messageData", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }); 
}

Context context;
String messageData;
esActivity activity;
```

}

Here is my call in onCreate of my MainActivity

```
     Notifier nt = new Notifier(getApplicationContext, MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Now It stuck in this while otherwise it gives nullpointer exception on toast

Comment: Are you getting this log - Log.d("Context", "issue"); Try @Henry answer.

Comment: yes I am getting..if I remove this it gives null pointer

Comment: Is this line _exactly_ how you have it in your code?: Notifier nt = new Notifier(getApplicationContext, MainActivity.this);

Comment: That would mean you have a variable called `getApplicationContext`, or it won't compile.

Comment: i mean I am passing getApplicationContext(), which is correct I guess

Comment: Please post the portion of your code where you call nt.toast().

Comment: actually I am calling this method from c++ using JNI ...but that should not be issue I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `activity` is null. Check your constructor:

```
public Notifier(Context ctx, MainActivity activity){
Log.d("Constructor call", "dd");
context = ctx;
activity = activity;
}
```

the assignment `activity = activity;` has no effect. What you want is

```
this.activity = activity;
```

Comment: Nope, still going inside while and both context and acitvity is null

Comment: How do you know both are `null`? And why do you have a loop there (activity and context won't change)?

Comment: I am checking in while for both one by one....it is just for check as it was giving null pointer exception

Comment: "I am checking in while for both one by one": what makes you think this is what's happening here? It will just spit out the log message every second until you kill the app.